Is there way to partially resolve git merge conflicts while leaving the rest unresolved?
I'm working on a tool to automate merge conflict resolution in a git pull request. It does this by locally cloning the repo, merging the two branches, and then going through each unmerged path and replacing the conflict regions with proposed resolution, when possible. It then creates a new PR to merge these resolutions into the feature branch.
My issue is that this tool cannot guarantee that 100% of the conflicts will be resolved. In that case, I want it to leave the unresolved conflicts so a developer can go in and manually fix them. Ideally, I want to be able to push the resolutions and have Git show the rest of the files as unmerged.
However, the problem is that when my tool creates new PR with the proposed resolutions, git no longer thinks that there are conflicts remaining. I'm wondering if there is a way to get around this so that git thinks I've only resolved some of the conflicts, but not all?
My current approach does the following:

The feature branch is merged into the destination branch and all possible conflicts are resolved:

# On feature branch
git checkout feature-branch
git merge dest-branch
# resolve all possible conflicts, but not necessarily all
git push --force

If a conflict cannot be resolved, it is "collapsed" by keeping the ours side (NOTE: I think this is problematic because it makes git think that I resolved the conflict by just keeping the "ours" side).

Resolutions are pushed to a new branch and the tool creates a PR to merge them into the feature branch
After this PR is merged, git shows no more conflicts, even if the tool did not resolve all of them.


A merge is an all-or-nothing operation. What you want to achieve is not possible if you want to keep the merge commit.

Thanks @j6t, I was wondering if this was possible with vanilla git and you're right that its not possible. I ended up using a different workflow that applies the proposed resolutions locally directly on the developers machine

One way to do it, make in-flight-merge side-branch tips on the existing ones, with any resolutions on both tips and the respective ours or theirs content as the "resolution" on each.
Another way: commit the partial merge results on a partial-merge branch, one for each team independently, replace anything they don't know the right result for with "We don't know the right resolution here either" markers.  Then merge all the partial merges and take the versions that aren't ~shrug~ markers.

After resolving the conflicts and adding the resolved files, the tool also runs git status -s > unresolved.log to save the output in unresolved.log. And then add all the unresolved files (if any) and unresolved.log and commit.
The developer updates the PR branch and views unresolved.log to check if there is any unresolved file. Reference the short format and focus on the unmerged files. Most unmerged files have conflict markers, so it will be obvious to resolve the conflicts. Some unmerged files like deleted by them do not have conflict markers, the developer decides to keep or remove the file.
After resolving the left conflicts, the developer removes unresolved.log and amend the merge commit to end the merge task.
The unmerged status in short format
D           D    unmerged, both deleted
A           U    unmerged, added by us
U           D    unmerged, deleted by them
U           A    unmerged, added by them
D           U    unmerged, deleted by us
A           A    unmerged, both added
U           U    unmerged, both modified

In unresolved.log it looks like
UU a.txt
UD b.txt
AA c.txt

